# calculation probability density function

Tags: function, matlab

I have a probability density function,

```
f(y) = a0*L_0 + a_neg*exp(A_neg *(y))*L_neg + a_pos*exp(-A_pos *(2-y))*L_pos, for 0<y<2.
```

All elements are available,

1. `a0` is scalar,
2. `L_0` is `1X5`,
3. `a_neg` is `1X3`,
4. A_neg `3X3`,
5. `L_neg` is `3X5`,
6. `L_pos` `1X5`,
7. `a_pos` is scalar,
8. `A_pos` is scalar.

Calculating it in matlab I get the result with no error,

```
% Define the function
f = @(y) a0*L_0 + a_neg*expm(A_neg * y)*L_neg + a_pos*exp(-A_pos * (2-y))*L_pos;
% Define the range of y
y = linspace(0, 2, 1000); % 1000 points between 0 and 2

% Initialize result matrix
result = zeros(length(y), 5);

% Compute the function for all y values
for i = 1:length(y)
    result(i, :) = f(y(i));
end

% Print the result
disp(result);
```

This works properly, but since its a pdf function I want to take the integral and get a `1X5` vector as pdf integral from `1` to `2` `f(y)dy` with this code,

```
    f_integral = integral(@(y) sum(f(y)), 0, 2);
```

I get error "Incorrect dimensions for matrix multiplication. Check that the number of columns in the first matrix matches the number of rows in the second matrix. To perform elementwise multiplication, use '.*'." if there is a problem in my dimensions why I dont get error when I calculate `f(y)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `ArrayValued` option to `true` as follows,

```matlab
f_integral = integral(@(y) sum(f(y)), 0, 2, 'ArrayValued', true);
```

The problem is when you provide the function with a set of scalars like `[1,2,3]`, it doesn't operate on every one of them individually. This is similar to what happens if the output itself is not a scalar but an array. That's why specifying that the output is an array even if it's actually not helps in this case.

Comment: Thank you for yor comment, but I still get the same error

Answer (score 1):

this helped

```
f_values = zeros(200, 5);   % Preallocate the matrix for f(y) values

for i = 1:200
    f_values(i, :) = f(y_values(i));
end

integral_value = trapz(y_values, f_values);
```